# After writing to a binary file and opening it with various programs, why are the results not as expected?

Tags: c++, notepad++, binaryfiles, openoffice.org, notepad

Basically I'm trying to write to a binary file so that when it is opened with a text editor it will display all ASCII characters. I noticed this works with notepad but doesn't work with notepad++ or open office and gives strange results. Why?

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    ofstream file ("file.bin", ios::binary);
    for(int num = 0; num < 128; num++)
        file.write (reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&num), sizeof(num));
    file.close ();
    return 0;
}
```

So I expect the file when opened with a text editor to roughly reproduce [this ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/). When I open it with notepad I get this

> ```
>    !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /   0
> ```
>
> 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ?   @   A   B 
>   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T 
>   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   [   \   ]   ^   _   `   a   b   c   d   e   f 
>   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x 
>   y   z   {   |   }   ~

When I open it with notepad++ I get this
[image: screen shot of notepad++]

When I open it with OpenOffice.org Writer I select the default option to open with "Western Europe (Windows 1252/WinLatin 1)" and get a bunch of `###`. Does this have to do with the byte-order-marker?

I tried modifying the program to use `file.write (reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&num), sizeof(char));` since the `int` is being type casted to a `char` but then the program crashes.

**Out of curiosity anyone got an explanation as to why OpenOffice writer comes up with `#` and spaces?**

Comment: You are getting all of ASCII, each seperated by three null characters.  Is that what you intended?  When you say it doesn't work, what does that mean?  What "strange results" do you see?   Does notepad++ crash?  Does it show Chinese?

Comment: @MooingDuck where does the three null characters come from? I updated the question.

Comment: Examinging your screenshot, Notepad++ is showing the correct output

Comment: @MooingDuck how do you arrive at that conclusion? 10 is ASCII for 'A' and I don't see any 'A's.

Comment: If you look closely, you can see that the output is in little-endian. Cool.

Comment: @Celeritas Open the output file in a hex editor. That "A" you're referring to isn't the ASCII letter "A" but it's the hexidecimal 0xA(10 in base 10) which corresponds to a line feed character.

Comment: @celeritas try to plug the notepad++ hex plugin and use it , you will see more clearly all the hexa decimal values you saved.

Comment: @Celeritas ASCII #10 is newline.  'A' is ASCII # 65.  Check your ASCII table again

Comment: @0x499602D2: I'd actually written 90% of my answer before I noticed that the fifth byte wasn't a zero and was confused for a moment.

Comment: Oh yea my mistake I red the chart wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for(int num = 0; num < 128; num++)
    file.write (reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&num), sizeof(num));
```

In these lines, you are writing the number `num` in binary, as a 4 byte integer.  (`sizeof(num)`, where `num` is an `int`).  Since all of the values you are writing are less than 128, the first three bytes of `num` are always `0x000000`.  So for each value you write, you're getting three nulls and then the ASCII character you intended.

Microsoft Notepad is absolutely stupid, and when it reaches an ASCII character that isn't printable, such as NULL, it simply displays a space.  Notice how your ASCII values have "spaces" between them.  Also, I bet it looks more like this, where I've replaced some spaces with underscores.  Note that the 10th value (new line) causes a new line.

```
_________
__            !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ?   @   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   [   \   ]   ^   _   `   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   {   |   }   ~
```

Notepad++ is much more intelligent, and instead of converting all the strange things to spaces, shows you their name or number.  Notepad++ also seems to have gotten confused by the character 13 (carriage return) by itself, since 13 is also usually part of a new line.  It (reasonably) decided to make that a new line as well.  Notepad++'s handling of this file is arguably more correct.  This can be verified by looking at the first eight characters: "`NUL NUL NUL NUL - SOH NUL NUL NUL`"  First is the zero, then the "SOH" character.  If we look at your ASCII chart, it says the first ASCII character is "SOH - Start of Heading".